# arcGIS 4.18 locate widget custom icon

Tags: arcgis, arcgis-js-api

I have to change the default icon on the Locate widget on arcGIS 4.18. The default icon class is, esri-icon-locate how can I change it to the class, 'esri-icon-navigation'?

I am going through the documentation,
https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-widgets-Locate.html#iconClass

I have tried to use the property, 'iconClass'. But not reflecting in the map icon. Please find the code below,

```
  var locateBtn = new Locate({
    view: view,
    // iconClass: '\ue666'
    iconClass: 'esri-icon-navigation'
  });
  view.ui.add(locateBtn, {
    position: "manual",
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

KER,

You actually right, does not work as expected. Setting `iconClass` should be the solution.

Funny fact if you check the default `iconClass` is actually `esri-icon-north-navigation`, which obviously in not.

Anyway, I am gonna give a dirty solution, just overlap the class you want,

```
view.when(_ => {
  const n = document.getElementsByClassName("esri-icon-locate");
  if (n && n.length === 1) {
    n[0].classList += " esri-icon-navigation"
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no" />
  <title>Locate button | Sample | ArcGIS API for JavaScript 4.18</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/4.18/esri/themes/light/main.css" />
  <style>
    html,
    body,
    #viewDiv {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
    }
  </style>
  <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/4.18/"></script>
  <script>
    require([
      "esri/Map",
      "esri/views/MapView",
      "esri/widgets/Locate"
    ], function (Map, MapView, Locate) {
      var map = new Map({
        basemap: "topo-vector"
      });

      var view = new MapView({
        container: "viewDiv",
        map: map,
        center: [-56.049, 38.485, 78],
        zoom: 3
      });

      var locateBtn = new Locate({
        view: view
      });

      // Add the locate widget to the top left corner of the view
      view.ui.add(locateBtn, {
        position: "top-left"
      });

      view.when(_ => {
        const n = document.getElementsByClassName("esri-icon-locate");
        if (n && n.length === 1) {
          n[0].classList += " esri-icon-navigation"
        }
      });

    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="viewDiv"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. The code is working! :)

Comment: My requirement got changed a bit. I have to add a custon svg file instead of the navigation icon from arcGIS. Here the problem is, the default icon is appearing top of the custom svg file. Is there any way to hide the default icon? Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Adam-KER, can you add a new question with this?, in order to not mix solutions.

Comment: Hi, Can you please have a look, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65670537/custon-svg-icon-on-arcgis-map-widget